# ReactJS: Rendering "Hello World" component doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I followed this guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html Added the .js file to the page, like so:

```
    <script src="{{ base_url }}/js/reactjs/like_button.js"></script>
```

And the like button was clickable and showed the "You liked this." when clicked.

Now, I wanted to try the Hello World guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html Adding a  element to the page, under the like button element. I added the following .js file to the page like so:

```
    <script type="text/jsx" src="{{ base_url }}/js/reactjs/helloworld.js"></script>
```

(I tried to add type="text/jsx", but it doesn't seem to help) But the #root element never shows "Hello world!".

Anything I'm missing here?

These are the JS (CDN) files I load in on the bottom of the page:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

I have NodeJS and NPM/X installed. But I haven't used it yet for this Hello World example.

In the end I only want React to be used as a View (MVC) component in my PHP Slim framework project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding babel to your project.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

And change the type to "text/babel" the script file.

```
<script type="text/babel" src="{{ base_url }}/js/reactjs/helloworld.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh it was that simple... Thanks a bunch sir. Is it because Firefox doesn't support all the ES6 stuff yet, or would Chrome have the same issue?